# How to restrict ng-repeat with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-if="post.type !='article'">
  <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
</div>
```

in the above code that will restrict only when 'artical' comes to the list then it will restrict.but In my scenario I have drop down that will add dynamically.Here I want to restrict already selected value should not be visible in the next added drop down.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbft1sc4/1658/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `filter` on `ng-repeat` collection, and pass `type` value dynamically there.

```
ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { type: selectedValue }"
```

Comment: @user9130953 is fiddle is incomplete? Not sure what to fix :(

Comment: what I need to pass in the place of selectedValue

Comment: @user9130953 I'd request you to update jsfiddle, so that I can fix it and provide you an working environment

Comment: please find the above fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/oLgLgcso/3/):

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="personalDetail.fname" ng-options="x for x in allowedNames(personalDetail.fname)">
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.allowedNames = function(current){
    var temp = $scope.names.filter(function(x){ 
        return $scope.personalDetails.map(function(x){ return x.fname}).indexOf(x) == -1 
    });
    temp.push(current);
    return temp;
}
```